# Safari can not find my webplugin

Tags: xcode, plugins, safari, webkit

I have developed a web plugin for Safari. It works correctly in XCode (debug), but it can not be found by Safari. The web plugin was copied in /Library/Internet Plug-Ins/.

Does someone know the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.When using xcode for debuging, the 32-bit plugin can be compiled.but only use safari run plugin,the plugin must be compiled 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Safari 5.1 and later no longer supports Webkit Plugins. (I assume you're talking about that and not an NPAPI plugin?)